# Can the CPU work with a RAM that has less than the supported frequency?

Tags: memory, cpu, compatibility

Intel provides the types and frequencies of memories supported by a certain CPU. Can the CPU work or be compatible with a RAM that has less than the stated frequency? can it cause any damage to either the CPU or the memory? Will it be a bottleneck?

To be more specific, "Intel® Core™ i7-8550U Processor" support these Memory Types: "DDR4-2400, LPDDR3-2133". Can it work with DDR4-2133 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[What’s specified](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122589/intel-core-i7-8550u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html) is the maximum supported type. That means this CPU supports DDR4 memory *up to* 2400 MHz or LPDDR3 memory *up to* 2133 MHz. It probably doesn’t support both at the same time though. You’ll also have to check what type the motherboard supports.

Additionally, you can also install faster modules. They will simply run slower, unless you manually overclock.

So yes, DDR4-2133 will definitely work, if the motherboard supports DDR4.

Comment: As much as I know, processors ending with 'U' letters are for ultra-low-power processors that are not overclockable.

Comment: Yes, it’s typically not possible (no options in the firmware setup). Still, it’s possible and theory and works the same way it does with desktop CPUs.